# Tradingview Pine script save close price at time of strategy entry

Tags: pine-script

Hey I'm trying to save the close price at the time of strategy.entry to a variable so I can use it later for an exit.

```
if condition
    strategy.entry("long", true)
    buyprice=close
(strategy.exit("exit","long", when = close>buyprice*1.1)
```

I get the error: `Undeclared identifier 'buyprice'`. From what I understand this means that the variable is not valid outside of the if statement. Is there a way to change this? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: declare buyprice in global scope

Comment: Why was this question protected? Just doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/support-pinescript-global-variables-available-during-any-bar-calculation) is the only way that I could get this to work.

Basically, you set the previous price when long condition is met and then retrieve that value from the global variables in the next phase.

```
//@version=2
...
buyprice=buyprice[1]


golong=...

if golong
    buyprice := close

goshort=... or close<=buyprice*0.95

strategy.entry("Long", long=true, when=golong)
strategy.close("Long", when=goshort)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so bugged and imcomplete

Comment: this does not work , `buyprice` is not updated

Comment: This seems like does not work , `buyprice` is never updated during strategies and I was not able to debug its value in order to verify it

Answer (score 1):

Add this AFTER to the code you use to enter a position:

```
bought = strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1]
entry_price = valuewhen(bought, open, 0)
```

Comment: What is function `valuewhen `?

Comment: this is the correct answer, the condition strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1]  is for LONGS,  for SHORTS is the <