# TradingView Pine Script : check previous strategy.entry price before new entry

Tags: pine-script

Someone asked a similar question with no response and I am not allowed to add to it.

[Tradingview Pine script save close price at time of strategy entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958139/tradingview-pine-script-save-close-price-at-time-of-strategy-entry)

I am trying to build a strategy that will buy multiple times (pyramiding) to average down before closing but I want to check the previous entry price to make sure it's less by a configured percentage.

What I have so far:

```
lastBuy=0

if (condition)
    if (lastBuy==0)
        lastBuy=close
        strategy.entry("buy", true)
    else
        if ((close*1.01)<lastBuy)
            lastBuy=close
            strategy.entry("buy", true)
```

Each time the code is passed it resets lastBuy back to zero and I never get to check the previous close price. If I don't set this I get undeclared error.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

How I am saving the entry price to a variable:

```
bought = strategy.opentrades[0] == 1 and strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1]
entry_price = valuewhen(bought, open, 0)
```

Comment: What does `valuewhen  function refer too?

Answer (score 5):

This works for entry price.

> `entryPrice = valuewhen(strategy.opentrades == 1, strategy.position_avg_price, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

> Each time the code is passed it resets lastBuy back to zero and I never get to check the previous close price. If I don't set this I get undeclared error.

This happens because your code tries to declare the same `lastBuy` variable repeatedly. Doing so gets you [TradingView's undeclared identifier error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/undeclared-identifier/).

To solve this situation, first declare your variable with `=`. Then update its value with `:=`. Just keep in mind that you can't use the `=` operator more than once on the same variable.

So change your code to:

```
lastBuy = 0

if (condition)
    if (lastBuy == 0)
        lastBuy := close
        strategy.entry("buy", true)
    else
        if ((close*1.01)<lastBuy)
            lastBuy := close
            strategy.entry("buy", true)
```

Comment: second else fives following error: `lines 129:135: Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (void; series[integer])`

Answer (score 0):

> The var keyword is a special modifier that instructs the compiler to
> create and initialize the variable only once. This behavior is very
> useful in cases where a variable’s value must persist through the
> iterations of a script across successive bars.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html

You should put "var" before "lastBuy" so it won't be reseted.

```
var lastBuy = 0

if (condition)
    if (lastBuy == 0)
        lastBuy := close
        strategy.entry("buy", true)
    else
        if ((close*1.01)<lastBuy)
            lastBuy := close
            strategy.entry("buy", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
last_entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
```